# How to install Appium driver for Codeception version higher than ~ 2

Tags: appium, codeception

When I try to install an appium driver in a Codeception project with the following command in the console:

> composer require me-io / appium-driver-codeception --with-all-dependencies

Then my system hails the following error:

```
 "Problem 1
     - me-io / appium-driver-codeception [1.0.0, ..., 1.0.1] require codeception / codeception ~ 2 -> found codeception / codeception [2.0.0,
  ..., 2.5.6] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (~ 4.1).
     - Root composer.json requires me-io / appium-driver-codeception ^ 1.0 -> satisfiable by me-io / appium-driver-codeception [1.0.0, 1.0
.1]. "
```

Has anyone installed an appium driver on a codeception project with a version higher than ~ 2. I can't find a solution to this error.

Answer (score 0):

The real question here is "What to do with abandoned open source project?".

The fix could be as simple as updating version constraint in composer.json file (and delete composer.lock file).
Make that change and raise pull request to original repo,
then you can install your change from the source right away.
If original maintainer does not respond, you can rename package in composer.json and publish it to packagist as your own.

Steps

1. Fork the project on Github
2. Make changes in your fork.
3. Raise pull request to original repo.
4. Update composer.json of  your project to install this package from your fork.
   4.1. Add [repositories section](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository):

   ```
       "repositories": [
           {
               "type": "vcs",
               "url": "https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/appium-driver-codeception"
           }
       ],
   ```

   4.2. Install from branch

   ```
   "require-dev": {
       "me-io/appium-driver-codeception": "dev-BRANCH-NAME"
   }
   ```